# Parsing a local JSON file into Coredata leads to an error

Tags: json, swift, core-data

I'm trying to parse a local JSON file which contains 3 dictionaries and each has its own array in Coredata, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x7fff86b93f10) to 'NSArray' (0x7fff86b92430).
```

I'm using the following code:

```
private func preloadData() {
    
    // Get a reference to User Defaults
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    
    // Get a reference to the persitent container
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    // Check if this is the first launch
    if defaults.bool(forKey: Constants.PRELOAD_DATA) == false {
        
        // Parse the Json
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "JSONProjectFinal", ofType: "json")
        
        // Check that path isn't nil
        guard path != nil else { return }
        
        // Create a URL
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
        
        do {
            // Get the data
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            
            // Attempt to parse the Json Array
            let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [[String:Any]]
            print(jsonArray)

            // Loop through the Json array
            for d in jsonArray {
                
                // Create the book objects and populate them
                
                // Populate the Fantasy books
                let f = Fantasy(context: context)
                f.name = d["name"] as? String
                f.imagename = d["imagename"] as? String
                f.date = d["date"] as? String
                f.summary = d["summary"] as? String
                
                // Populate the Adventure books
                let a = Adventure(context: context)
                a.name = d["name"] as? String
                a.imagename = d["imagename"] as? String
                a.date = d["date"] as? String
                a.summary = d["summary"] as? String
                
                // Populate the SciFi books
                let sci = SciFi(context: context)
                sci.name = d["name"] as? String
                sci.imagename = d["imagename"] as? String
                sci.date = d["date"] as? String
                sci.summary = d["summary"] as? String
            }

        } catch { return }
```

And here's a snippet of the JSON file

```
{
    "fantasy": [
        {
            "name": "Fellowship of the Ring",
            "imagename": "lotr",
            "date": "24 July 1964",
            "summary": "The Fellowship of the Ring is the first of three volumes in The Lord of the Rings, an epic set in the fictional world of Middle-earth. The Lord of the Rings is an entity named Sauron, the Dark Lord, who long ago lost the One Ring that contains much of his power. His overriding desire is to reclaim the Ring and use it to enslave all of Middle-earth"
        },
        {
            "name": "Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows",
            "imagename": "harrypotter",
            "date": "21 July 2007",
            "summary": "Without the guidance and protection of their teachers, Harry, Ron and Hermione set out on a mission to destroy the horcruxes, which are the sources of Voldemort's immortality. Although they must trust each other more than ever, forces of darkness threaten to separate them. Voldemort's Death Eaters have taken control of the Ministry of Magic and Hogwarts, and they are looking for Harry as he and his friends prepare for the final confrontation."
        }
    ]
}
```

So, how should I go about this? Should I cast this as a dictionary of arrays?
I'm fairly new to programming in general so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not an answer, but I recommend that you switch to the `Codable` protocol instead of `JSONSerialization`. You can paste your JSON [here](https://app.quicktype.io/) and it will generate your data model for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your root is a dictionary not an array so

```
guard let res = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:[:]) as? [String:Any] ,  
      let jsonArray = res["fantasy"] as? [[String:Any]] else { return }
```

Comment: This worked for me for the first Dictionary, but how can I add the remaining two?